# Calculate Daily Active Users with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Iam a RoR developer and I want to calculate **DAU** for my website. By DAU I mean:

**DAU- Total Number of users who either came to my website and logged in or who came to the website and were already logged in.**

I implemented [**Devise**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) in my website because it tracks current_sign_in_at. And later found that these attributes mean as:

**current_sign_in_at** - The latest time the person logged in to my website. 
(Using this I can get the count of people who came to my website and logged in.)

**But I am missing the count of people who came to the website and were already logged in.**

One of the way I found to implement it is trigger a function in delayed job which updates the timestamp whenever the root action is called and home page of my website loads. But since my website gets around 1000 - 2000 hits per minute I guess this function will become the bottleneck.

Can anyone please suggest me the best way to implement it.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

- Use a service like Google Analytics(custom variables), KISSmetrics(visitor identity) or Mixpanel(distinct_id) and send them the user id and you can find daily active users.
- You can do something like what you mentioned, store the last active time for the user in a database each time you get a request, if you get 1000-2000 hits per minute, you might want to store it in an in memory store like redis instead. If users will be coming to your website from different paths and not just root url you could create a after_filter in the application controller which updates the redis store with the current time for the user.
- If you are interesting in looking at more then just the daily active users in future, it is worthwhile to create a log for your users in another database. Again I'd suggest an before or after_filter in application_controller which queues a job to store time, user_id, any other data you might be interested in. I'm using a mongo db separate from my ActiveRecord MySQL database to do this.